# Special Kind of ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, scrollview, minimize, maximize

So I have my game, made with SpriteKit and Obj-C. I want to know a couple things.

**1) What is the best way to make scroll-views in SpriteKit?**

**2) How do I get this special kind of scroll-view to work?**

The kind of scroll-view I'd like to use is one that, without prior knowledge, seems like it could be pretty complicated. You're scrolling through the objects in it, and when they get close to the center of the screen, they get larger. When they're being scrolled away from the center of the screen, they get smaller and smaller until, when their limit is met, they stop minimizing. That limitation goes for getting bigger when getting closer to the center of the screen, too.

Also, I should probably note that I have tried a few different solutions for cheap remakes of scroll views, like merely adding the objects to a SKNode and moving the SKNode's position relative to the finger's, and its movement . . . but that is not what I want. Now, if there is no real way to add a scroll-view to my game, this is what I'm asking. Will I simply have to do some sort of formula? Make the images bigger when they get closer to a certain spot, and maybe run that formula each time `-touchesMoved` is called? If so, what sort of formula would that be? Some complicated Math equation subtracting the node's position from the center of the screen, and sizing it accordingly? Something like that? If that's the case, will you please give me some smart Math formula to do that, and give it to me in code (possibly a full-out *function*) format?

If **ALL** else fails, and there is no good way to do this, what would some other way be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is possible to use UIScrollViews with your SpriteKit scenes, but there's a bit of a workaround involved there. My recommendation is to take a look at this [github project](https://github.com/bobmoff/ScrollKit), that is what I based my UIScrollView off of in my own projects. From the looks of it, most of the stuff you'd want has actually been converted to Swift now, rather than Objective-C when I first looked at the project, so I don't know how that'll fare with you.
2. The project linked above would result in your SKScene being larger than the screen (I assume that is why it would need to be scrolled), so determining what is and is not close to the center of the scene won't be difficult. One thing you can do is use the update loop in SpriteKit to constantly update the size of Sprites (Perhaps just those on-screen) based on their distance from a fixed, known center point. For instance, if you have a screen of width and height `10`, then the midpoint would be `x,y = 5,5`. You could then say that size = `1.0 - (2 * distance_from_midpoint)`. Given you are at the midpoint, the size will be `1.0` (`1.0 - (2 * 0)`), the farther away you get, the smaller your scale will be. This is a crude example that does not account for a max or min fixed size, and so you will need to work with it.

Good luck with your project.

**Edit:**

Alright, I'll go a bit out of my way here and help you out with the equation, although mine still isn't perfect.

[image]

Now, this doesn't really give you a minimum scale, but it will give you a maximum one (Basically at the midpoint). This equation here does have some flaws though. For one, you might use this to find the `x` and `y` scale of your objects based on their distance from a midpoint. *However*, you don't really want two different components to your scale. What if your Sprite is right next to the x midpoint, and the x_scale spits out 0.95? Well, that's almost full-sized. But if it is far away from the midpoint on the `y` axis, and it gives you a `y` scale of, say 0.20, then you have a problem.

To solve that, I just take the magnitude or hypotenuse of the vector between the current coordinate and the coordinate of the current sprite. That hypotenuse gives me an number that represents the true distance, which eliminates the problem with clashing scale values.

I've made an [example](http://play.golang.org/p/klFpApYaSk) of how to calculate this inside Google's Go-Playground, so you can run the code and see what different scales you get based on what coordinate you plug in. Also, the equation used in there is *slightly* modified, It's basically the same thing as above but without the `maxscale -` part of the front part of the equation.

Hope this helps out!

Embedding Attempt:

[see this code in play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/klFpApYaSk)

Comment: Thanks, Owatch! That second point definitely helped me, as I'm pretty bad at coming up with ideas like that. Point one doesn't really help me, because it's in Swift. Although I do understand Swift, I'm not good at converting between the two languages. Maybe I'll use it, maybe I won't. Thanks for sharing the github project, anyway. I'll one-up this answer, and wait for others. If none other come, this is good enough to consider my accepted answer. Again, thanks!

Comment: No problem, if you need the code for the UIScrollView integration in Objective-C, I'll could try to extract it. Or try to contact the owner of the github project.

Comment: OK, so how would I implement this math to adjust the image's size? I tried to mess with your formula a bit, and it didn't work out too well. Have any ideas?

Comment: @ChristianKRider I've modified my original answer to better address the math part.

Comment: OK, so after some experimentation both in my Xcode project and in your example playground thingy, I found that it doesn't work very well. If the distance of pixels away from the center of the screen is ***more*** than (an educated guess) 100 pixels, the scaling gets too small. Apparently, when the x-scale and y-scale gets too small in SpriteKit, it goes the reverse. What the reverse does is makes the image bigger again, and flips the image upside-down. I tried finding the absolute value of the numbers instead, but that didn't work. Can you help me figure out what went wrong here? Thnx!

Comment: A quick fix would be to follow up the scale value with an if-statment. `if (scale > some_minimum_like_zero){ // scale = my_minimum};` How does that work

Comment: Well yes, that does constrain the minimum size, but then they all revert to the minimum size, and I can't figure out how to make the center ones bigger. Here's the code I'm still messing with right now: `CGFloat scale; CGFloat distance = [self distanceBetweenPoint:_centerOfScreen andPoint:button.position]; scale = 1.0 - ((distance / 10.0) * 2.0); if (scale < 0.5) { scale = 0.5; } button.xScale = scale; button.yScale = scale;`

Comment: @ChristianKRider Wait, I don't understand. If the scale is less than 0.5, then it will be fixed to 0.5. So, how are they all reverting to minimum size if only those that are smaller than 0.5 get set? The center ones should just be bigger anyways, what is going wrong there? Could you provide some clarification on the problem?

Comment: OK, so here's what's happening. The distance is too great for this equation. It would work fine if the distance were in something like centimeters, because then the numbers would always be below something like 50. But because we're working with pixels, here, it doesn't work. That if-statement locking the minimum size works fine, but because no matter what they're always smaller than 0.5, they all end up that way. Not even the ones in the center get bigger. Trust me, I have already tried to mess with the numbers, making them smaller (the "/10.0" in my code snippet), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, then you're just not supplying the equation correctly. Because as long as your sprites are inside a defined frame, and you supply a coordinate within that frame, then it will give it a proper size. Doesn't matter if you have 1000x1000 unit frame, or 10x10 unit frame. If the scales are too small for you, replace the `1.0` that is your maximum scale with `2.0`. This will ensure that even if they are the maximum distance away from the center, they will be larger than 0.5. Try this inside the Google Go playground.

Comment: I will. For my information, is this also what I'm looking for: [Apple Docs UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:)? If not, I'll continue to work on your solution. Your solution is a good one, I'm just trying to figure out how to meet my personal needs. Also, while I'm at it, how can I loop through the objects and see which one is the biggest, so I can set that one to max? Then the scaling looks more dramatic.

Comment: What do you mean, you want these to scale exponentially rather than linearly? Or you just want to find one of them, and scale it to some maximum size? You should be able to easily loop through your Sprites on-screen. Normally, I place them all in an Array for easy access. But if you can't do this for some odd reason, you can access the children of the parent Sprite they are added to, and get them there. However, if they aren't the only things added to this sprite, it will be a problem. You will need to filter by class type, and if that isn't possible, subclass the resizable ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88737/discussion-between-christian-k-rider-and-owatch).